# ADFS Custom Claim to return group DNs

Tags: adfs3.0

I have had no luck in writing a custom claim rule to return the distinguishedName of the user's groups instead of just the name of the group.  Are there any ADFS Custom Claim Rule ninja's out there who could help me out with this challenge?

For example, the default return is MYGroupName, but I need to return CN=MyGroupName,OU=Groups,DC=Domain,DC=local

Answer (score 0):

@Pierre answered [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/76900672-d296-456d-948a-2384f2328075/custom-claim-rule-for-group-dn?forum=ADFS) over on the ADFS forum.

For reference:

c1:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 && c2:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid"]
 => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://group/DN"), query = "(&(objectClass=group)(objectSID={1}));distinguishedName;{0}", param = c1.Value, param = c2.Value);